# Checking for null pointers or allowing a math library to segfault?

Tags: error-handling, pointers, null, error-detection

I've been going through the [GNU GSL design document](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/design/gsl-design_toc.html) and came across this interesting line in the Test suites section:

> N.B. Don't bother to test for null pointers -- it's sufficient for the library to segfault if the user provides an invalid pointer.

Having prepared for the Microsoft technical interview in the past many study resources are quite explicit in teaching you to show the interviewer that you can properly test for invalid inputs into functions. Typically a correct function implementation would test for all possible invalid inputs, many of them NULL pointers, before doing any work.

How can these two differing approaches be reconciled? Which one is correct? What would a Microsoft interviewer say if you refuse to test for NULL pointers if you say that you've seen production code ignore them?

Comment: It makes no sense, and it provides no value to test for invalid inputs if there is nothing useful you can do about it.

Comment: Allowing a preventable segfault to occur seems like a bad strategy to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: but what is the library supposed to do about it? This is C, so if you want some sort of error reporting mechanism, that's more complexity, more expense, more risk of bugs. The GSL puts the onus of preventing those segfaults on the callers, and in many situations that's the right thing to do.

Comment: @whatsisname: Are modern operating systems resilient enough to always and reliably handle what amounts to an invalid memory access?  I thought the whole point of a segfault was to prevent something bad happening from an *unexpected* invalid memory access.

Comment: I think the short answer to your question is yes: any modern memory-mapped operating system can handle invalid memory accesses. Very few programmers are coding to physical memory these days, and those that are will not be calling high-level libraries like GSL.